# JRuby OpenSSL Exception

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, jruby, jruby-openssl

After setting up jruby for the first time, OpenSSL is causing an exception when attempting to do a bundle install. The project does not include any SSL gems other than what is built in to jruby.

JRuby version:

```
jruby 1.7.4 (1.9.3p392) 2013-05-16 2390d3b on Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM 1.6.0_65-b14-462-11M4609 [darwin-x86_64]
```

Exception:

```
bundle install
/Users/user/.rvm/rubies/jruby-1.7.4/lib/ruby/shared/openssl.rb:25 warning: already initialized constant PKCS1_PADDING
/Users/user/.rvm/rubies/jruby-1.7.4/lib/ruby/shared/openssl.rb:25 warning: already initialized constant SSLV23_PADDING
... (more similar warnings)
Unfortunately, a fatal error has occurred. Please see the Bundler
troubleshooting documentation at http://bit.ly/bundler-issues. Thanks!
OpenSSL.java:197:in `isDebug': java.lang.NullPointerException
    from OpenSSL.java:201:in `debugStackTrace'
    from X509Store.java:184:in `set_default_paths'
    from X509Store$INVOKER$i$0$0$set_default_paths.gen:-1:in `call'
    from CachingCallSite.java:306:in `cacheAndCall'
    from CachingCallSite.java:136:in `call'
    from CallNoArgNode.java:60:in `interpret'
    from NewlineNode.java:105:in `interpret'
    from BlockNode.java:71:in `interpret'
    from IfNode.java:118:in `interpret'
    from NewlineNode.java:105:in `interpret'
    from BlockNode.java:71:in `interpret'
    from ASTInterpreter.java:74:in `INTERPRET_METHOD'
    from InterpretedMethod.java:139:in `call'
    from DefaultMethod.java:170:in `call'
    from CachingCallSite.java:306:in `cacheAndCall'
    from CachingCallSite.java:136:in `call'
    from VCallNode.java:88:in `interpret'
    from AttrAssignOneArgNode.java:33:in `interpret'
    from NewlineNode.java:105:in `interpret'
    from BlockNode.java:71:in `interpret'
    from IfNode.java:116:in `interpret'
    from NewlineNode.java:105:in `interpret'
    from BlockNode.java:71:in `interpret'
    from BeginNode.java:83:in `interpret'
    from InstAsgnNode.java:95:in `interpret'
    from OpAsgnOrNode.java:102:in `interpret'
    from NewlineNode.java:105:in `interpret'
    from ASTInterpreter.java:74:in `INTERPRET_METHOD'
    from InterpretedMethod.java:139:in `call'
    from DefaultMethod.java:170:in `call'
    from CachingCallSite.java:306:in `cacheAndCall'
    from CachingCallSite.java:136:in `call'
    from VCallNode.java:88:in `interpret'
    from NewlineNode.java:105:in `interpret'
    from BlockNode.java:71:in `interpret'
    from ASTInterpreter.java:74:in `INTERPRET_METHOD'
    from InterpretedMethod.java:204:in `call'
    from DefaultMethod.java:194:in `call'
    from CachingCallSite.java:336:in `cacheAndCall'
    from CachingCallSite.java:179:in `callBlock'
    from CachingCallSite.java:183:in `call'
    from RubyClass.java:855:in `newInstance'
    from RubyClass$INVOKER$i$newInstance.gen:-1:in `call'
    from JavaMethod.java:294:in `call'
    from CachingCallSite.java:326:in `cacheAndCall'
    from CachingCallSite.java:170:in `call'
    from CallOneArgNode.java:57:in `interpret'
    from NewlineNode.java:105:in `interpret'
    from ASTInterpreter.java:112:in `INTERPRET_BLOCK'
    from Interpreted19Block.java:206:in `evalBlockBody'
    from Interpreted19Block.java:157:in `yield'
    from Block.java:142:in `yield'
    from RubyArray.java:2404:in `collect'
    from RubyArray.java:2417:in `map19'
    from RubyArray$INVOKER$i$0$0$map19.gen:-1:in `call'
    from CachingCallSite.java:316:in `cacheAndCall'
    from CachingCallSite.java:145:in `callBlock'
    from CachingCallSite.java:154:in `callIter'
    from CallNoArgBlockNode.java:64:in `interpret'
    from InstAsgnNode.java:95:in `interpret'
    from OpAsgnOrNode.java:102:in `interpret'
    from NewlineNode.java:105:in `interpret'
    from ASTInterpreter.java:74:in `INTERPRET_METHOD'
    from InterpretedMethod.java:139:in `call'
    from DefaultMethod.java:170:in `call'
    from CachingCallSite.java:306:in `cacheAndCall'
    from CachingCallSite.java:136:in `call'
    from VCallNode.java:88:in `interpret'
    from CallOneArgNode.java:57:in `interpret'
    from DAsgnNode.java:110:in `interpret'
    from NewlineNode.java:105:in `interpret'
    from BlockNode.java:71:in `interpret'
    from ASTInterpreter.java:112:in `INTERPRET_BLOCK'
    from Interpreted19Block.java:206:in `evalBlockBody'
    from Interpreted19Block.java:157:in `yield'
    from Interpreted19Block.java:135:in `yieldSpecific'
    from Block.java:120:in `yieldSpecific'
    from YieldOneNode.java:35:in `interpret'
    from NewlineNode.java:105:in `interpret'
    from BlockNode.java:71:in `interpret'
    from ASTInterpreter.java:74:in `INTERPRET_METHOD'
    from InterpretedMethod.java:161:in `call'
    from DefaultMethod.java:178:in `call'
    from CachingCallSite.java:316:in `cacheAndCall'
    from CachingCallSite.java:145:in `callBlock'
    from CachingCallSite.java:154:in `callIter'
    from CallNoArgBlockNode.java:64:in `interpret'
    from InstAsgnNode.java:95:in `interpret'
    from OpAsgnOrNode.java:102:in `interpret'
    from NewlineNode.java:105:in `interpret'
    from ASTInterpreter.java:74:in `INTERPRET_METHOD'
    from InterpretedMethod.java:139:in `call'
    from DefaultMethod.java:170:in `call'
    from CachingCallSite.java:306:in `cacheAndCall'
    from CachingCallSite.java:136:in `call'
    from /Users/user/.rvm/gems/jruby-1.7.4@global/gems/bundler-1.7.12/lib/bundler/source/rubygems.rb:72:in `__file__'
    from /Users/user/.rvm/gems/jruby-1.7.4@global/gems/bundler-1.7.12/lib/bundler/source/rubygems.rb:-1:in `__file__'
    from JittedMethod.java:141:in `call'
    from CachingCallSite.java:306:in `cacheAndCall'
    from CachingCallSite.java:136:in `call'
    from /Users/user/.rvm/gems/jruby-1.7.4@global/gems/bundler-1.7.12/lib/bundler/lazy_specification.rb:53:in `__file__'
    from /Users/user/.rvm/gems/jruby-1.7.4@global/gems/bundler-1.7.12/lib/bundler/lazy_specification.rb:-1:in `__file__'
    from JittedMethod.java:141:in `call'
    from CachingCallSite.java:306:in `cacheAndCall'
    from CachingCallSite.java:136:in `call'
    from CallNoArgNode.java:60:in `interpret'
    from DAsgnNode.java:110:in `interpret'
    from NewlineNode.java:105:in `interpret'
    from BlockNode.java:71:in `interpret'
    from ASTInterpreter.java:112:in `INTERPRET_BLOCK'
    from Interpreted19Block.java:206:in `evalBlockBody'
    from Interpreted19Block.java:157:in `yield'
    from Block.java:142:in `yield'
    from RubyArray.java:2430:in `collectBang'
    from RubyArray.java:2449:in `map_bang'
    from RubyArray$INVOKER$i$0$0$map_bang.gen:-1:in `call'
    from CachingCallSite.java:143:in `callBlock'
    from CachingCallSite.java:154:in `callIter'
    from CallNoArgBlockNode.java:64:in `interpret'
    from NewlineNode.java:105:in `interpret'
    from BlockNode.java:71:in `interpret'
    from ASTInterpreter.java:74:in `INTERPRET_METHOD'
    from InterpretedMethod.java:182:in `call'
    from DefaultMethod.java:186:in `call'
    from CachingCallSite.java:326:in `cacheAndCall'
    from CachingCallSite.java:170:in `call'
    from CallOneArgNode.java:57:in `interpret'
    from LocalAsgnNode.java:123:in `interpret'
    from NewlineNode.java:105:in `interpret'
    from BlockNode.java:71:in `interpret'
    from BeginNode.java:83:in `interpret'
    from InstAsgnNode.java:95:in `interpret'
    from OpAsgnOrNode.java:102:in `interpret'
    from NewlineNode.java:105:in `interpret'
    from ASTInterpreter.java:74:in `INTERPRET_METHOD'
    from InterpretedMethod.java:139:in `call'
    from DefaultMethod.java:170:in `call'
    from CachingCallSite.java:306:in `cacheAndCall'
    from CachingCallSite.java:136:in `call'
    from VCallNode.java:88:in `interpret'
    from NewlineNode.java:105:in `interpret'
    from BlockNode.java:71:in `interpret'
    from ASTInterpreter.java:74:in `INTERPRET_METHOD'
    from InterpretedMethod.java:139:in `call'
    from DefaultMethod.java:170:in `call'
    from CachingCallSite.java:306:in `cacheAndCall'
    from CachingCallSite.java:136:in `call'
    from CallNoArgNode.java:60:in `interpret'
    from IfNode.java:118:in `interpret'
    from NewlineNode.java:105:in `interpret'
    from IfNode.java:118:in `interpret'
    from NewlineNode.java:105:in `interpret'
    from BlockNode.java:71:in `interpret'
    from ASTInterpreter.java:74:in `INTERPRET_METHOD'
    from InterpretedMethod.java:182:in `call'
    from DefaultMethod.java:186:in `call'
    from CachingCallSite.java:326:in `cacheAndCall'
    from CachingCallSite.java:170:in `call'
    from CallOneArgNode.java:57:in `interpret'
    from NewlineNode.java:105:in `interpret'
    from BlockNode.java:71:in `interpret'
    from ASTInterpreter.java:74:in `INTERPRET_METHOD'
    from InterpretedMethod.java:268:in `call'
    from DefaultMethod.java:218:in `call'
    from CachingCallSite.java:366:in `cacheAndCall'
    from CachingCallSite.java:238:in `call'
    from CallThreeArgNode.java:61:in `interpret'
    from NewlineNode.java:105:in `interpret'
    from BlockNode.java:71:in `interpret'
    from RescueNode.java:222:in `executeBody'
    from RescueNode.java:117:in `interpret'
    from ASTInterpreter.java:74:in `INTERPRET_METHOD'
    from InterpretedMethod.java:139:in `call'
    from DefaultMethod.java:170:in `call'
    from CachingCallSite.java:306:in `cacheAndCall'
    from CachingCallSite.java:136:in `call'
    from CallNoArgNode.java:60:in `interpret'
    from NewlineNode.java:105:in `interpret'
    from BlockNode.java:71:in `interpret'
    from ASTInterpreter.java:74:in `INTERPRET_METHOD'
    from InterpretedMethod.java:161:in `call'
    from DefaultMethod.java:178:in `call'
    from RubyClass.java:578:in `finvoke'
    from RubyBasicObject.java:1703:in `send19'
    from RubyBasicObject$INVOKER$i$send19.gen:-1:in `call'
    from JavaMethod.java:347:in `call'
    from CachingCallSite.java:326:in `cacheAndCall'
    from CachingCallSite.java:170:in `call'
    from CallSpecialArgNode.java:67:in `interpret'
    from NewlineNode.java:105:in `interpret'
    from BlockNode.java:71:in `interpret'
    from IfNode.java:116:in `interpret'
    from IfNode.java:118:in `interpret'
    from NewlineNode.java:105:in `interpret'
    from BlockNode.java:71:in `interpret'
    from RescueNode.java:222:in `executeBody'
    from RescueNode.java:117:in `interpret'
    from ASTInterpreter.java:74:in `INTERPRET_METHOD'
    from InterpretedMethod.java:225:in `call'
    from DefaultMethod.java:202:in `call'
    from CachingCallSite.java:346:in `cacheAndCall'
    from CachingCallSite.java:204:in `call'
    from CallSpecialArgNode.java:69:in `interpret'
    from NewlineNode.java:105:in `interpret'
    from BlockNode.java:71:in `interpret'
    from IfNode.java:118:in `interpret'
    from NewlineNode.java:105:in `interpret'
    from BlockNode.java:71:in `interpret'
    from ASTInterpreter.java:74:in `INTERPRET_METHOD'
    from InterpretedMethod.java:225:in `call'
    from DefaultMethod.java:202:in `call'
    from CachingCallSite.java:346:in `cacheAndCall'
    from CachingCallSite.java:204:in `call'
    from CallTwoArgNode.java:59:in `interpret'
    from NewlineNode.java:105:in `interpret'
    from BlockNode.java:71:in `interpret'
    from ASTInterpreter.java:74:in `INTERPRET_METHOD'
    from InterpretedMethod.java:112:in `call'
    from InterpretedMethod.java:126:in `call'
    from DefaultMethod.java:161:in `call'
    from CachingCallSite.java:296:in `cacheAndCall'
    from CachingCallSite.java:72:in `call'
    from FCallManyArgsNode.java:60:in `interpret'
    from NewlineNode.java:105:in `interpret'
    from BlockNode.java:71:in `interpret'
    from RescueNode.java:222:in `executeBody'
    from RescueNode.java:117:in `interpret'
    from ASTInterpreter.java:74:in `INTERPRET_METHOD'
    from InterpretedMethod.java:247:in `call'
    from DefaultMethod.java:210:in `call'
    from SuperCallSite.java:386:in `cacheAndCall'
    from SuperCallSite.java:238:in `callBlock'
    from SuperCallSite.java:243:in `call'
    from SuperCallSite.java:109:in `callVarargs'
    from ZSuperNode.java:103:in `interpret'
    from NewlineNode.java:105:in `interpret'
    from RescueNode.java:222:in `executeBody'
    from RescueNode.java:117:in `interpret'
    from ASTInterpreter.java:74:in `INTERPRET_METHOD'
    from InterpretedMethod.java:225:in `call'
    from DefaultMethod.java:202:in `call'
    from CachingCallSite.java:346:in `cacheAndCall'
    from CachingCallSite.java:204:in `call'
    from CallTwoArgNode.java:59:in `interpret'
    from NewlineNode.java:105:in `interpret'
    from BlockNode.java:71:in `interpret'
    from ASTInterpreter.java:112:in `INTERPRET_BLOCK'
    from Interpreted19Block.java:206:in `evalBlockBody'
    from Interpreted19Block.java:157:in `yield'
    from Interpreted19Block.java:130:in `yieldSpecific'
    from Block.java:111:in `yieldSpecific'
    from ZYieldNode.java:25:in `interpret'
    from NewlineNode.java:105:in `interpret'
    from RescueNode.java:222:in `executeBody'
    from RescueNode.java:117:in `interpret'
    from ASTInterpreter.java:74:in `INTERPRET_METHOD'
    from InterpretedMethod.java:161:in `call'
    from DefaultMethod.java:178:in `call'
    from CachingCallSite.java:316:in `cacheAndCall'
    from CachingCallSite.java:145:in `callBlock'
    from CachingCallSite.java:154:in `callIter'
    from CallNoArgBlockNode.java:64:in `interpret'
    from NewlineNode.java:105:in `interpret'
    from BlockNode.java:71:in `interpret'
    from RootNode.java:129:in `interpret'
    from ASTInterpreter.java:121:in `INTERPRET_ROOT'
    from Ruby.java:834:in `runInterpreter'
    from Ruby.java:2674:in `loadFile'
    from ExternalScript.java:66:in `load'
    from LoadService.java:359:in `load'
    from RubyKernel.java:1081:in `loadCommon'
    from RubyKernel.java:1073:in `load19'
    from RubyKernel$INVOKER$s$0$1$load19.gen:-1:in `call'
    from DynamicMethod.java:209:in `call'
    from DynamicMethod.java:205:in `call'
    from CachingCallSite.java:326:in `cacheAndCall'
    from CachingCallSite.java:170:in `call'
    from FCallOneArgNode.java:36:in `interpret'
    from NewlineNode.java:105:in `interpret'
    from BlockNode.java:71:in `interpret'
    from RootNode.java:129:in `interpret'
    from ASTInterpreter.java:95:in `INTERPRET_EVAL'
    from ASTInterpreter.java:184:in `evalWithBinding'
    from RubyKernel.java:1130:in `evalCommon'
    from RubyKernel.java:1093:in `eval19'
    from RubyKernel$INVOKER$s$0$3$eval19.gen:-1:in `call'
    from DynamicMethod.java:225:in `call'
    from DynamicMethod.java:221:in `call'
    from CachingCallSite.java:366:in `cacheAndCall'
    from CachingCallSite.java:238:in `call'
    from /Users/user/.rvm/gems/jruby-1.7.4@global/bin/jruby_executable_hooks:15:in `__file__'
    from /Users/user/.rvm/gems/jruby-1.7.4@global/bin/jruby_executable_hooks:-1:in `load'
    from Ruby.java:807:in `runScript'
    from Ruby.java:800:in `runScript'
    from Ruby.java:669:in `runNormally'
    from Ruby.java:518:in `runFromMain'
    from Main.java:390:in `doRunFromMain'
    from Main.java:279:in `internalRun'
    from Main.java:221:in `run'
    from Main.java:201:in `main'
```

Comment: 1.7.4 is quite old; the current release is 1.7.18.

Answer (score 0):

This appears to have been caused by a problem installing jruby. I was able to resolve it by upgrading the JDK, and by upgrading RVM before installing jruby again.